# Track event form query string in google analytics

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I’m trying to track downloads from a page with different URL’s with google analytics.

That is I am sending tree URL’s out: and I need to track which of the URL people are visiting and downloading from.

```
http://www.testsite.com/?id=One
http://www.testsite.com/?id=Two
http://www.testsite.com/?id=Tree
```

I make the URL with a query string and I try to use the “id” in “onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',…”

```
<a href="http://www.testsite.com/test.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Marketing', 'PDF', ???]);">test.pdf</a>
```

What should I write instead of “???”

Comment: "one", "two" or "tree" would be my guess.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the content of the page - It has to be the same for every page - it is only the query string that changes.
And the "id" has no other effekt on the page.

Comment: Hook up the event handlers using JavaScript at page-load time instead of doing them inline. Then you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Thanks again. I have just very little understanding of javascript. Can you show me how?

Comment: How about: 
`onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Marketing', 'CV', window.location.href);` ?

Comment: That would work. Sure.